# Automate Java Cucumber test cases in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, cucumber-java, azure-releases

I'm trying to integrate Cucumber tests written in maven, and pushed/associated the test cases using SpecSync.

I'm suppose to run this automation tests. I see without VsTest task the automation runs are not possible. In case of adding this task, it fails when triggered - No test assemblies found.
Is there any way I can skip this task for my project or add with some other configurations or is there any way from specsync to achive E2E integrations of these automation test runs.